# gsub in for loop not running?

Tags: r, loops, gsub

For some reason, this gsub line in my for loop isn't executing. Basically, what I hope to do is for a specific character at the beginning and end of an element, I would like to take it out. So in my example code, I only keep values that start with 0 or get rid it it otherwise (in the code I'm working with everything stored in the matrix is a character vector, and what I want to do is remove a repeating specific character at the beginning and end of each vector). However, nothing is changed about m2 once my script finishes running

```
m2 <- matrix( c(2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2), nrow=3, ncol=3)
rownames(m2) <- c("a", "d", "e")
colnames(m2) <- c("x", "w", "z")

for (i in 1:length(rownames(m2))){
  for (j in 1:length(colnames(m2))){
    if (substr(m2[i,j], 1, 1) == "0") {
      m2 <- m2
    } else (m2 <- gsub("^.", "", m2))
  }
}
```

Comment: replaced with m2, mat was part of my original script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `m2` to replace anything which doesn't start with 0 you can use `startsWith`

```
m2[!startsWith(as.character(m2), "0")] <- ''
m2

#   x   w   z  
#a ""  "0" "0"
#d "0" ""  "0"
#e "0" "0" ""
```

Comment: how would do this with a character string? so say i had a bunch of random strings and I want to get rid of all the "a"s that occur at the start and end of a string such that a string like "abba" would become "bb"?

Comment: @JohnAbercrombie This doesn't seem related to data `m2` that you have shown. Please update your post with the data that you have and show expected output for that.

Comment: You probably need `gsub('^a|a$', '', 'abba')` ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(m2, m2 != 0, "")
#    x   w   z  
#a ""  "0" "0"
#d "0" ""  "0"
#e "0" "0" ""
```

If we need to `replace the values that doesnt start with '0'

```
replace(m2, substr(m2, 1, 1) != 0, "")
#   x   w   z  
#a ""  "0" "0"
#d "0" ""  "0"
#e "0" "0" ""
```